# Changing output with ChannelBot

Tags: php, bots, reddit

I'm using a Reddit bot named [ChannelBot](https://github.com/jariz/ChannelBot/tree/master/lib/ChannelBot) - I'm trying to change what the title is submits to Reddit is, and am struggling.
At the moment, it outputs 'videotitle [time]'.

It looks like this is the line that submits to Reddit, but not sure where to track it back to from here:

```
if (!in_array($item->contentDetails->videoId, $channel["last_videos"])) {
//we've got one!
$success = $this->reddit->submit(
$channel["subreddit"],
"link",
$item->snippet->title,
$this->config->prepend . $item->contentDetails->videoId
);
```

I'm just trying to adjust it to 'channelname - videotitle [time]'. Any help, or a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```
$success = $this->reddit->submit(
$channel["subreddit"],
"link",
"[".$channel['channel']."] - ".$item->snippet->title,
$this->config->prepend . $item->contentDetails->videoId
);
```